# d3.js radial tree layout variable node length / text wrap node description

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a radial hierarchy on d3.js based on mbostock's reingold-tilford tree example.
The block on bl.ocks.org is here: http://bl.ocks.org/ratnakarv/43087fb7f373338bf62c

Considering root node is 'Level 0', the text at some nodes at level 2 and some nodes at level 3 is encroaching on child node's text.
I am possible looking at two solutions:
1. Increasing the length of edges as the levels increase (as text length increases with levels in hierarchy)
2. including a word wrap function to give a neater look

or a combination of two.

Appreciate if some one can point me to ideas/code examples to incorporate these

[Note: I have a basic idea of d3.js. I am not a data visualizer  and primarily constructing these visualizations to describe my main work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3's tree layout populates the `x` and `y` attributes on the data when you call `tree.nodes()`. Now it's just a matter of manipulating the `y` values to "spread out" the tree so that there's enough space between each level for your text.

A straightforward method of doing this is to simply scale each node's `y` value based on its depth. After the tree layout is created, do:

```
nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sk7krdrp/1/

You may even want to make the scaling a function of the maximum node text length.

This makes the tree a lot bigger, but it looks like that's what you want, as long as the texts don't overlap. If you want to keep the tree smaller and wrap text so that longer text appears in two or more lines, you could do that by wrapping each "line" in a tspan ([example here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321)). Of course, you will have to move around the neighboring nodes so that the wrapped text of a node doesn't overlap its neighbors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the depth based modification and with trial and error, got the required scaling.
d.name.length based scaling also looked attractive, but I want to preserve a major characteristic of reingold-tilford tree - all nodes of equal depth are at the same level. with d.name.length, that will be affected.
Thanks again